# I can't get the value of my select element when i have a hidden field that is revealed if an option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a select form element with various options. One of the options is "other". So when "other" is selected a hidden field is displayed for the user to enter the value not on the list. All that works fine. The problem is when a user selects any of the other options and submits the form, the value is not passed. Whereas, if the "other" option is selected and fills the text box then submits the form, the value of the text box is passed.

this is the select and the hidden text field:

```
<select name="memo" required class="newtxtbox" id="memo" onchange='checkvalue()'>
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="Donation for Bulletin">Bulletin</option>
  <option value="Donation for Care Ministry">Care Ministry</option>
  <option value="Donation for Cathedral Choir">Cathedral Choir</option>
  <option value="Donation for Other">Other - (please specify below) </option>
</select>

<input type="text" style="display:none" name="memo" id="other">
```

and this is JavaScript:

```
function checkvalue()       
{
    if(document.getElementById('memo').value == 'Donation for Other') {
               document.getElementById('other').style.display='block';
    }
    else {
       document.getElementById('other').style.display='none'; 
    }
}
```

I am sure i am missing something small but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: An easy solution to this (you can submit a form with two input elements that has the same name, but involves slightly more work) is to rename your input field to `otherMemo` and at the server, when the "donation for other" is selected, retrieve the value by parameter name `otherMemo`

Comment: @Lindow 2 Yes you can. let me see what that looks like

Comment: @KarelG I had thought of that also as a last resort if i could not get the present code to work

Comment: Do you realize that the problem is at the server (thus not at js)? Your code works fine. When you submit the form, the `memo` param is an array which contains value from the `<select>` element **and** the `<input type="text">` element.  If you don't have access to that code, then I can provide you a workaround.

Comment: @KarelG How is it an array? Please can you explain a bit. Thought it was supposed to just be a simple value from A or value from B. A being the select options and B being the hidden input field.

Comment: Eh... It's not an array unless you add a `[]` in the `name` attribute. I mean that the - since the form has two inputs with same `name` attribute - form processing overwrites the `name`  field if it exists. So if the value of your `input` is valid (so containing text), it will overwrite the value from the `select`.

Comment: @KarelG Oh okay. I understand. So can you post the workaround you offered earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a visual example of a small workaround. What I did was simply changing the `name` attribute of each element. I have added a CSS rule that displays the element with `name="memo"` as blue. The element that is blue will be sent to the server.

I have also expanded the javascript code so that you can test it out here on SO. You don't have to include the code after `// added for testing purpose` in your code. Click on "run code snippet" and try the submit button.

```js
function checkvalue() {
  var select = document.getElementById('memo');
  var input = document.getElementById('other');

  if (select.value == 'Donation for Other') {
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
    select.name = '';
    input.name = 'memo'; // form `memo` will now contain this input 
  } else {
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
    select.name = 'memo';
    input.name = '';
  }
}

// added for testing purpose
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // no no submit

  // FormData is HTML5 js object that contains ... data from the form ...
  var fd = new FormData(this);

  // .entries() isn't widely supported yet.
  for (var tuple of fd.entries()) {
    console.log(tuple[0] + ' contains value "' + tuple[1] + '"');
  }
});
```

```css
/* 
   added this for visibility of changes
    element that is blue is being sent
*/

input[name="memo"],
select[name="memo"] {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <select name="memo" required class="newtxtbox" id="memo" onchange='checkvalue()'>
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="Donation for Bulletin">Bulletin</option>
  <option value="Donation for Care Ministry">Care Ministry</option>
  <option value="Donation for Cathedral Choir">Cathedral Choir</option>
  <option value="Donation for Other">Other - (please specify below) </option>
</select>

  <input type="text" style="display:none" id="other">

  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes a whole lot of sense. Will change my codes to this. What i had done initially was to change the `name` of the `select` to `memo1` and the `name` of the `input` field to `memo2`. The on the server side implemented a conditional statement that `if ($memo1 != "Donation for Other") {
  $memo = $memo1;
 }else{
  $memo = "Donation for"." ".$memo2;
 }`

Comment: So at the end of the day what is submitted is whatever is in `$memo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. Really appreciate it.